# Is it correct to say "Best Regards"?

Tags: grammar, correspondence

This is my gmail email signature

```
Best Regards,
Rory
```

Recently it's started to bother me. I feel it might be improper english. Is it?

Is it an acceptable sign off?

Comment: Perfectly fine, thought there are dozens of options.  Maybe you should find some others and alternate.

Answer (score 1):

It may be regarded as a bit old-fashioned, but it is acceptable, and perfectly proper. (US)

Comment: It is fine as a closing for a letter.  It is "old fashioned" only to the extent that letters are "old fashioned".